# Asynchronous multithreading in Restful Web Services

Tags: rest, netbeans, web, service, glassfish

I am developing a restful web service, deployed in Glassfish 4 and programmed in Java using Netbeans and Jersey, that can have long execution times ( in some cases over 4-5 minutes ). In order to keep the user updated with no actions on his part and prevent timeout errors from the browsers, I decided to start the main thread that processes the request and return an html page that redirects to another restful web page that tests if the request is completed with a slight delay.

The problem is that the first web service is waiting for the thread to finish before returning the html response, so the thread is pretty much useless. Is there any way to bypass that ?

Here is this first service:

```
@GET
@Produces("text/html")
public String getXml(@QueryParam("id") String id) {
    Random rand=new Random((new Date()).getTime());
    long clientId=rand.nextLong();
    MainTestingThread mtt=new MainTestingThread(id,clientId);
    mtt.run();
    return "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta HTTP-EQUIV=\"refresh\" CONTENT=\"10;URL=/checkstatus?clientid="+clientId+"\"/></head><body>Analysis Started and your clientID is \""+clientId+"\".<br/>Please wait...</body></html>";
}
```

Thanks and sorry if I missed any info but I am pretty new to web services.

Comment: Have you considered using asynchronous calls? https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/async.html. It is a built-in mechanism for long term calls.

Comment: I am pretty new to web services so I had no idea there was a built in mechanism... Thank you, I will check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research and a good night's sleep I figured it out. The problem was that I used mtt.run() instead of mtt.start() so it tried running it on the same thread.